# Change legend labels ggscatter plot in r studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, scatter-plot

I am trying to change the labels of the legend in my ggscatter plot.

This is my code:

```
plot=ggscatter(ALL, x = "CSdepth", y = "Cslength",
          add = "reg.line", 
          cor.method = "pearson", color="SPECIES", palette = "jco", shape="SPECIES", fullrange = TRUE,
          xlab = "Depth of the central sulcus (mm)", ylab = "Length of the central sulcus (mm)")+ggtitle("Correlation length and depth of the central sulcus")+
  stat_cor(aes(color = SPECIES))
```

This is the graph I am getting:

[image]

I tried adding the following:

```
plot+scale_color_discrete(name = 'Species', labels = c("Chimpanzee","Gibbon","Gorilla","Oerangutan"))
```

with as result:

[image]

How can I remove the other legend? I have tried multiple codes such as show.legend=FALSE but nothing seems to work... Can anyone help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: I can't recreate your result since you didn't post any data, but you could try adding `+ guides(shape = guide_none())`

Comment: Finally! Thank you so much! How something so small can keep you busy for so long